Scanner (SHARP MX-3060N) scans pages then throws feeder empty exception C# WPF, NAPS2
I will begin saying I'm not an expert so if there's already a solution to this or this isn't the right place to post this I apologize and I'll correct it.
That said I tried scanning with my printer a bunch of paper and have it convert it int PDF docs using the code posted in the NAPS2 SDK .NET:
// Set up
using var scanningContext = new ScanningContext(new GdiImageContext());

var controller = new ScanController(scanningContext);

// Query for available scanning devices
var devices = await controller.GetDeviceList();

// Set scanning options
var options = new ScanOptions
{
Device = devices.First(),
PaperSource = PaperSource.Feeder,
PageSize = PageSize.A4,
Dpi = 300
};

// Scan and save images
int i = 1;
await foreach (var image in controller.Scan(options))
{
image.Save($"page{i++}.jpg");
}

// Scan and save PDF
var images = await controller.Scan(options).ToListAsync();
var pdfExporter = new PdfExporter(scanningContext);
await pdfExporter.Export("doc.pdf", images);

When I attempt to run the program I get this exception:
An exception of type 'NAPS2.Scan.Exceptions.DeviceFeederEmptyException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll but was not handled in user code
Non ci sono fogli nell'alimentatore automatico.
(There are no papers in the automatic feeder) even though it scans the pages in the feeder.
I tried changing params and researching anyone that had a similar problem but it seems it's only me for now, or everyone can figure it out but me which may very well be the case.
I get the error whenever the "Scan()" method launches and I'm at a loss.
What am I missing?

coworkers will realize I'm bad at coding...A nervous imposter.: Seems like a learning opportunity for you.

@user246821 Just an attempt at humour, I have made a couple research softwares and a (very tiny) smartwatch OS, I'm just slow on this thing HEH.

Some scanner have a paper feeder and others do not.  Scanners with paper feeder you usually have the option to manually place the document on the scanner directly or use the paper feeder.  You need to read the manual to determine the settings for the scanner (https://www.manualslib.com/products/Sharp-Mx-3060n-4211104.html).  Your setting say PaperSource = PaperSource.Feeder so you are requiring the document to be placed in the feeder.  The error says there is no paper in the feeder.

@jdweng Yes I have placed paper in the Feeder, when I launch the method the paper goes inside and gets out of the feeder, then after a second I get the exception saying I have no paper inside, even though it just went through the feeder.

Put a few sheet of paper in the feeder and see what happens.  I think it expects more than one sheet.

So the problem was actually my printer, I changed printer specifying drivers in the "options" as:
Driver = Driver.Wia (WIA or TWAIN in this case) and it worked like a charm.
I would also like to point out that I did indeed comment the first Scan method so to only leave the second one (which saved the PDF scan) active and it kept throwing the exception, apparently changing the printer saved the day.
Thanks to all those in the comments who tried to help, you're appreciated.
